# SQL JOIN query where datetime is X hours previous to current time

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

1. tickets
2. ticket_updates

the columns are:

`tickets` table

1. ticketnumber

`ticket_updates` table

1. ticketnumber
2. datetime

`ticketnumber = ticketnumber` in both tables. there are multiple rows in `ticket_updates` for each 1 row in the `tickets` table.

i want to run a query where the last row in the ticket_updates table is 1 hour or more previous to the current time. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
select t.*
from tickets t join
     (select ticketnumber, max(datetime) as maxdt
      from ticket_updates tu
      group by ticketnumber
     ) tu
     on t.ticketnumber = tu.ticketnumber
where tu.maxdt < now() - interval 1 hour;
```

You can also write this using a `not exists` clause:

```
select t.*
from tickets t
where not exists (select 1
                  from ticketupdates tu
                  where tu.ticketnumber = t.ticketnumber and
                        tu.datetime >= now() - interval 1 hour
                 );
```

This will probably perform better if you have an index on `ticketupdates(ticketnumber, datetime)`.